# Why does dereferencing occur only once in this while loop in C/C++?

Tags: c++, c

Why is *str in the following fragment dereferenced only once? It takes the first character of the string 'a' and keeps incrementing this value until it reaches the end of the ASCII table, contrary to my expectation of dereferencing it on every condition evaluation and resulting in the infinite loop. This behavior does change even if the dereference is moved from the condition to the body of the loop. GCC version 7.4.0 was used to test the code.

```
int getLen(char *str){
    int count=0;
    while((*str)++) {
        count++;
    }
    return count;
}

int main(){
    char s[]="abc";
    printf("length is %d\n",getLen(s));
}
```

Output:
159

Comment: Just **un**obfuscate the code by doing `while(*str) { str++ ...` instead and you are fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The expression `(*str)++` says, dereference `str` first, then increment the dereferenced value. It never increments `str` itself (the pointer). 
So, to answer your question, it's not that `str` is being dereferenced only once, it's dereferenced every time in the loop, but it never gets incremented hence the dereferenced memory is same every time.

Comment: This is exactly what I expected. This should be the infinite loop, but it is not what I observe.

Comment: I got it. (*s)++ means s[0] = s[0] + sizeof(s[0])

Comment: @user1602 (*s)++ means s[0]++

Comment: This won't be an infinite loop because you're always incrementing the value of the first memory location, that is the character 'a', which has ascii value 97, now if you increment it 30 times 97+30 = 127, that's the maximum value for a signed char, incrementing it further makes it -128, incrementing it further 128 times makes it 0 which breaks the loop. Total increments are 30 + 1 + 128 = 159, which matches your output.

Comment: @rogme Overflowing a signed integer type is not defined to wrap. It is Undefined Behaviour. Wrapping is only well defined for unsigned types.

Answer (score 8):

It is dereferenced 159 times, not just once.

The ASCII value of `a` is `97`.  If you increment that `159` times, you get `0`.

`(*str)++` doesn't increment `str`, it increments the first character in `str`.

It doesn't increase it "until it reaches the end of the ASCII table", it increases until it becomes `0`.  If your `char` type is signed, that means that it increments it to the maximum of that type, then from the minimum (a negative value) up to `0`.

Typically, `char` is signed and 8-bits.  In that case, it will increase to `127`, the next value will be `-128` and after that it will keep increasing until it becomes `0`.

If you want to use parentheses for clarity, use

```
while (*(str++)) 
{
    count++;
}
```

That is the same as

```
while (*str++)
{
    count++;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for clarifying about the ASCII table. My question is not about the how to increment the address, but about the dereference. Why it happens only once? Why it does not increment 'a' all the time?

Comment: It is dereferenced 159 times.  
The ASCII value of `a` is `97`.  If you increment that `159` times, you get `0`.

Comment: This is my point. Why dereference happens only once? Why it does not increment 'a' every time?

Comment: What do you mean ?  After the first increment, the `a` becomes `b`.  The next time, it becomes `c`.  And so on.

Comment: I think it's actually ANSI, isn't it?

Answer (score 6):

The term `(*str)++` is the source of your problem. You have added `()` around `*str`, which makes sure that `*str` is evaluated first and that value is incremented. It never increments `str`. Use `*str++` instead.

```
while(*str++) {
    count++;
}
```

Comment: My question was not about the correctness of the syntax for the string traversing. I am wondering why dereference happens only once.

Comment: @user1602, it is dereferenced every time the term is executed but it dereferences same pointer value.

Comment: Obviously the dereference is executed only once, otherwise it would be the infinite loop.

Comment: @user1602, it does not go into infinite loop because incrementing the first character causes it to become the null character at some point.

Comment: Thank you, finally I got it! It increments the character in place. Maybe you should edit your answer explaining it so I can accept it. Now I understand that (*s)++ means s[0] = s[0] + 1.